# Python: Trying to validate input such as a phone number to ensure it is 10 numerical characters and prompt and error if not

Tags: python, loops, validation

I want the program to remove ()'s and -'s which could possibly be entered when some one enters their phone #. I also want to make sure that is is 10 numerical characters long if not produce a loop.

```
p = raw_input("Please enter your 10 digit Phone Number")
def only_numerics(p):
    seq_type= type(p)
    return seq_type().join(filter(seq_type.isdigit, p))
p = only_numerics(p)

valid_phone = False
while not valid_phone:

    if p > "0000000000" and p < "9999999999" and len(p) == 10 :
        print "You have entered " + p
        valid_phone=True
    else:
        print "You have entered an invalid choice"
```

If I type in less than 10 numbers I get repeating of the else print command. I would like it to go back to raw input ("please enter your 10 digit Phone Number"). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, put a `while` loop around the whole block of code. The `while` loop should repeat if `!valid_phone`

Comment: Side note: instead of using `and` you could do `"0000000000" < p "9999999999"` using comparison chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from setting the "raw_input" inside the loop as James pointed out, you might be interested in using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and make your code more beautiful:

```
import re
phone_re = re.compile(r'\d{10}$')

def only_numerics(p):
    seq_type= type(p)
    return seq_type().join(filter(seq_type.isdigit, p))

valid_phone = False
while not valid_phone:
    p = raw_input("Please enter your 10 digit Phone Number: ")
    p = only_numerics(p)
    if phone_re.match(p):
        print "You have entered " + p
        valid_phone=True
    else:
        print "You have entered an invalid choice"
```

Answer (score 1):

It loops back to the print statement because you define p outside of the while loop. Changing this will fix the looping issue:

```
valid_phone = False
while not valid_phone:

    p = raw_input("Please enter your 10 digit Phone Number")
    def only_numerics(p):
        seq_type= type(p)
        return seq_type().join(filter(seq_type.isdigit, p))
    p = only_numerics(p)


    if p > "0000000000" and p < "9999999999" and len(p) == 10 :
        print "You have entered " + p
        valid_phone=True
    else:
        print "You have entered an invalid choice"
```

Comment: You cannot compare strings like that; conversion to int will allow you to compare

Comment: I've tested the code and it works just fine, besides its a simple answer using the OP's code to show the flaw in the code structure

Answer (score 0):

def val_number(input_num):

```
valid_num=re.findall(r'\d+',input_num)
if len(valid_num[0])>10:
    print('You have entered more than 10 digits')
else:
    return(valid_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

This python code validates an 11 digit mobile number:

```
valid = True
mobile_number = str(input("What is your mobile number? "))
while len(mobile_number) != 11 or mobile_number[0] != "0" or mobile_number[1:].isdigit() == False:
    mobile_number = str(input("Please enter a valid mobile number: "))
    valid = False
print("Your mobile number is valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

while(True):

```
try:
    phone_number=int(input("please enter the phone number:no spaces in between: \n"))
except ValueError:
    print("mismatch")
    continue
else:
    phone=str(phone_number)
    if(len(phone)==10):
        break
    else:
        print("10 digits please ")
        continue
```